# Hold a pair of values of the same type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, types

Background:
At one point, for my user, I need to store a pair of the same object type ( Setting ), and currently I have it like

```
Dictionary<long, List<KeyValueType<Setting, Setting>>> SettingKeyPairs
```

I am creating KeyValuesTypes with settings and adding it in a list ( each user has a list)
My settings have a Value field (it shows if they're 'more important'than the other Setting) so I would want to add them based on that and later I need to search based on that( and on a Name field maybe ) as well - so the search will have to look in the List and then in the KeyValueTypes

Question:
What would be the best data to use instead of KeyValueTypes? For the adding /searching part when I need to do it based on a specific value/values it it cumbersomeme. I've tried with Tuple as well but still don't think it's okay.

Comment: A custom class?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say from your questions- maybe I don't fully understand it. But I would probably store a list of the `Setting` type and expose a getter that returns the highest Value (or whatever the criteria is).

```
public class RankedSettings
{
   public RankedSettings(IEnumerable<Setting> settings)
   {
      _settings = settings;
   }

   private readonly IEnumerable<Setting> _settings;


   public Setting GetHighestValue() => _settings.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
}

...

var userSettingsCollection = new Dictionary<long, RankedSettings>();

...

var settings = userSettingsCollection[userId]?.GetHighestValue();
```

and you could of course wrap this up even more so that you override the dictionary getter to perform that GetHighestValue() call for you.